# Inremental Learning with hmmlearn or alternatives

Tags: python, hidden-markov-models, hmmlearn

I have a very large data set. I am using hmmlearn but as there is no support for incremental learning, it will not work due to memory constraints.

Is there any alternative or work around to chunk the data or support for hmmlearn with incremental learning?

Comment: It's not incremental learning but, if the states are pretty consistent across the whole data set, you could consider training the HMM on a subset, and using the trained model to classify the remaining data (rather than train on the whole data). I don't know if this is possible in hmmlearn, but this is described in Section 2 of a vignette for the R package hmmTMB: "[Advanced features of hmmTMB](https://github.com/TheoMichelot/hmmTMB/blob/master/vignettes/hmmTMB_advanced_features.pdf)"